# Formatting cells based on initial format [Very slow!]

Tags: c#, excel

I want to create an application which exports Excel files into HTML files using the Excel interop dll. One catch is that I want to make sure the .HTML file preview looks as close to reality as if it was being viewed in Excel.

When normally exporting Excel files as HTML files no borders / 'grid lines' are shown. To fix this issue [you must add your own borders.](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/352580-grid-lines-save-as-web-page.html)

However when Excel renders [coloured cells, grid lines are not shown.](http://cdn.get-digital-help.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Count-cells-by-conditional-formatting-color.png)

I wrote the below C# code to add borders to cells that have "no fill":

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace CS_HelloExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //Create excel application:
            Application application = new Application();

            //Define filename "C:\Users\sancarn\Documents\"
            String filename = "C:\\Users\\sancarn\\Documents\\myFormatedXL.xlsx";

            //Open workbook as read only, don't update links
            Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(filename, false, true);

            foreach (Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
            {
                Range ur = sheet.UsedRange;
                ur = ur.Resize[ur.Rows.Count + 1, ur.Columns.Count + 1];

                //Create individual cells where blank cells originally occur - Takes 0.2s
                ur.Replace("", "'");

                // Takes 3.4s
                foreach(Range cell in ur.Cells)
                {
                    if(cell.Interior.Pattern == -4142)
                    {
                        Borders b = cell.Borders;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle= XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].ThemeColor = 3;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 2;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle= XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].ThemeColor = 3;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight = 2;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle= XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].ThemeColor = 3;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 2;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle= XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].ThemeColor = 3;
                        b[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = 2;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Save workbook as html file takes 0.5s
            application.DisplayAlerts = false;
            workbook.SaveAs("myFormatedXL.html",XlFileFormat.xlHtml);

            //Get workbook path
            String path = workbook.FullName;

            //Close application
            workbook.Close(false);
            application.Quit();

            //Free up memory
            application = null;
        }
    }
}
```

However as shown in the comments the the loop over all the cells takes 3.5 seconds... I was wondering if anyone knows how I can speed up this task?

Comment: If you are working with xlsx files you should stop using the interop classes and use the open xml sdk from Microsoft instead

Comment: @ScottChamberlain ideally it would be for all Excel formats. But we could add some check for that :) A friend of mine also suggested https://epplus.codeplex.com/ for xlsx format.

Comment: ClosedXML is an awesome library to interact with xlsx. Sadly it doesn't support older xls format.

Answer (score 0):

This option seems to have better results:

```
//Takes 0ms?
Range b=null;
foreach(Range cell in ur.Cells)
{
    if(cell.Interior.Pattern == -4142)
    {
        b = b!=null ? application.Union(b, cell) : cell;
    }
}

b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].ThemeColor = 3;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = 2;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].ThemeColor = 3;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = 2;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].ThemeColor = 3;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight = 2;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].ThemeColor = 3;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = 2;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].ThemeColor = 3;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideHorizontal].Weight = 2;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].ThemeColor = 3;
b.Borders[XlBordersIndex.xlInsideVertical].Weight = 2;
```

First we make the range that needs to be formatted, and then afterwards we apply the formatting. However for some reason the formatting that comes as a result of this is... odd (in the resulting html file).

I might want to do this in CSS instead.